# SQL. How to obtain unique values from table but only for 1 column?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table1 . I sort this table by name, and  by time column :

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM table1
WHERE time >= '2022-05-23 00:00:00' AND time <= '2022-05-23 01:00:00'  
ORDER BY name, time
```

AS result i got next table :

```
    name,   value,  time
    A,      5,      2022-05-23 01:01:12
    A,      9,      2022-05-23 01:02:11
    A,      7,      2022-05-23 01:03:21
    B,      5,      2022-05-23 01:04:23
    B,      6,      2022-05-23 01:05:33
    C,      7,      2022-05-23 01:06:30
    C,      8,      2022-05-23 01:07:41
    C,      3,      2022-05-23 01:08:44
    C,      7,      2022-05-23 01:09:50
```

Then i need select all unique names with lowest time, and got values for this names:

Result should be like this:

```
name,   value,  time
A,      5,      2022-05-23 01:01:12
B,      5,      2022-05-23 01:04:23
C,      7,      2022-05-23 01:06:30
```

=====================================================================

It turns out that we just took each first unique name from the table:

```
name,   value,  time
A,      5,      2022-05-23 01:01:12 <- take this one
A,      9,      2022-05-23 01:02:11
A,      7,      2022-05-23 01:03:21 
B,      5,      2022-05-23 01:04:23 <- take this one
B,      6,      2022-05-23 01:05:33
C,      7,      2022-05-23 01:06:30 <- take this one
C,      8,      2022-05-23 01:07:41
C,      3,      2022-05-23 01:08:44
C,      7,      2022-05-23 01:09:50
```

My goal is take unique names with lowest timestamp (or each first unique name from table, because it's already sorted by timestamp)

I'm not clear how to get wanted result.
I tried use "SELECT DISTINCT name,values" but it's back all unique names AND unique values, but i'm need got ONLY unique names+values (where time is lowest)

Comment: which database are you using ? you can try SQL PARTITION BY and select only the first value by patition, in your case it's name,value, here is a link on how to do it : https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-partition-by-clause-overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `argMin` aggregation function (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/argmin/) to achieve the desired result. If you need to get the latest row, there is the `argMax` aggregation function (https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/argmax/).

The idea of `argMin/argMax` is to return the argument for the min or max of a given value (`time`, in your use case).

Sample data:

```
select * from table1; 

SELECT *
FROM table1

┌─name─┬─value─┬────────────────time─┐
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:12 │
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:12 │
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:12 │
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:12 │
│ A    │     9 │ 2022-05-23 01:02:11 │
│ A    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:03:21 │
│ B    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:04:23 │
│ B    │     6 │ 2022-05-23 01:05:33 │
│ C    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:06:30 │
│ C    │     8 │ 2022-05-23 01:07:41 │
│ C    │     3 │ 2022-05-23 01:08:44 │
│ C    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:09:50 │
└──────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘

12 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

As you need the whole row (and `argMin/argMax` require a single argument), it needs to be converted to another structure (a tuple in this example) and then projected back to their names. The following query returns the first (or the argument for the minimum value of `val` expression):

```
SELECT 
    tpl.1 AS name, 
    tpl.2 AS value, 
    tpl.3 AS time
FROM (
    SELECT 
        argMin(tuple(*), time) as tpl
    FROM 
        table1 
    GROUP BY name
)
ORDER BY name


┌─name─┬─value─┬────────────────time─┐
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:12 │
│ B    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:04:23 │
│ C    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:06:30 │
└──────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘


3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.004 sec.
```

As `argMax` works in a similar way but to get the latest (or argument for the maximum value of the `val` expression), this will give you the latest (most recent) name/value/time rows:

```
SELECT
    tpl.1 AS name,
    tpl.2 AS value,
    tpl.3 AS time
FROM
(
    SELECT argMax(tuple(*), time) AS tpl
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY name
)
ORDER BY name ASC


┌─name─┬─value─┬────────────────time─┐
│ A    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:03:21 │
│ B    │     6 │ 2022-05-23 01:05:33 │
│ C    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:09:50 │
└──────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

Comment: Edited: copied output of `argMax` for both queries - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would use `ROW_NUMBER`, but Clickhouse does not support analytic functions.  We can use a join approach instead:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, MIN(time) AS min_time
    FROM table1
    WHERE time >= '2022-05-23 00:00:00' AND time <= '2022-05-23 01:00:00'
    GROUP BY name
) t2
    ON t2.name = t1.name AND
       t2.min_time = t1.time
WHERE
    time >= '2022-05-23 00:00:00' AND time <= '2022-05-23 01:00:00';
```